# Dynamic attributes for a model

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, erd

I'm currently creating a document management system where the user should be able to configure the supported document types and therefor the documents attributes. My current conceptional ERD for the template looks like this:
[image: ERD for dynamic attributes]

but if i would like store my documents in this way, i it would create for each document with 2 attributes 3 entries in my database ( 1 for the document, and for each attribute another entry). In my opinion, i would do this the following way:
[image: ERD to store document data]

In my opinion, this doesn't look very cool. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the attributes a fixed set?

In this case the upper (`m:n`) looks better, but I think you don't need the `attribute name` but rather the actual `value` in the mapping table. The mapping table may be enhanced by some columns to identify additional data like who, when, why and maybe - if needed - to allow sort of soft-delete.

The second is `1:n` and will define the same attribute names over and over.

Think in `meta` and `instance`: It is meta-data, how your attribute is named. You might define a complex meta-modell, which attributes fit to which context. You might introduce multi-language support. Only the value (and additional data describing the mapping itself) is instance-data.

Comment: yes, sorry, attribute name is default from vision and i forgot it to delete ;)

my idea was to have the upper ERD as a configuration how the software defines the templates for serveral types of documents. So there will be only one DocumentType "Bill" and one "Letter" with its attributes. 

the bottom ERD would represent the meta-data to save from the documents into the database.

Comment: @BinaryFr3ak, never mind... Do you allow to add new attributes on run-time? That would be the only tricky part as you have to insert the new attribute **before** you can save the mapping row. In this case you might think about an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`...

Comment: No, i don't want this feature because it's easier without. Its just a small project for myself :-)